# Two Logos in One Page Website

Tags: website-design, gui-design, color, color-scheme

I have a question on the color combination that I will use since I have a website that **two logos** should be placed.

My problem is that the two logos have very different color schemes. The first logo has **blue and red** while the second logo has **green and black**.

What colors should I place on my website? I'm thinking that I should go with the main logo which is **blue and red**.

Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: Well, as the designer, that is up to you to decide which colour scheme works best for your branding requirements.

Comment: Can you share a little more about what the two logos represent? Is one your company and the other a product? Or are they two companies that went through a recent merger, etc?

Comment: @Izquierdo. two companies who developed a product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If red and blue are your main brand colors and the red and blue logo is the dominant brand, those are the colors you'll want on your site. If the green and black logo looks out of place, see if the partner company will let you use a one-color version of it - all white, all black, all gray.

Comment: They don't care if what color as long as their logo is there. I'm thinking of using the red and blue cause red, blue, green and black combined are not good

Comment: I would agree that having too many colors would be distracting.

Comment: Why just the partner company? Why not use single-color version for both? (Something like the logos in the bottom of movie posters)

Comment: The "main logo" is red and blue, and color is an important part of their brand. If the two companies were equals, monochrome might be a good solution, but I inferred from the question that the red and blue company was in a dominant position.

Answer (score 0):

The colors should derive from the logo / brand guidelines and should be based on the most relevant logo. As you haven't explained why there are two logos I assume 2 cases.

- Main company logo + subbrand -
- Company logo + partner logo.